# Java - Running a subprocess works locally but fails with "broken pipe" when ran on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku, runtime, uci

Just as a background, I have a Java-based Discord bot deployed on Heroku using the 1 free worker dyno. I need to run a .exe file (stockfish 12 executable), pass input into it and process output from it. I'm using Java RunTime to create this Process but when I try to send input to it with the flush() method the broken pipe error is thrown. I assume Heroku must be closing the input / output stream somehow because this code runs fine locally. Does Heroku have a limit on creating sub processes?

app[worker.1]: chess.player.ai.stockfish.exception.StockfishEngineException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
app[worker.1]: at chess.player.ai.stockfish.engine.UCIEngine.sendCommand(UCIEngine.java:39)
app[worker.1]: at chess.player.ai.stockfish.engine.UCIEngine.passOption(UCIEngine.java:77)
app[worker.1]: at chess.player.ai.stockfish.engine.UCIEngine.(UCIEngine.java:23)
app[worker.1]: at chess.player.ai.stockfish.engine.Stockfish.(Stockfish.java:13)
app[worker.1]: at chess.player.ai.stockfish.StockFishClient.(StockFishClient.java:21)
app[worker.1]: at chess.player.ai.stockfish.StockFishClient$Builder.build(StockFishClient.java:80)

EDIT: I tried to simplify the program by hard coding a single command and it still fails to get past the writer.flush() line. Nothing is printed.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("bin/stockfish_20090216_x64_bmi2.exe").start();

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("position fen rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1" + "\n");
writer.write("go movetime 1000");
writer.flush();

String line;
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}

int exitVal = process.waitFor();
if (exitVal == 0) {
    System.out.println("success");
    System.out.println(output.toString());
}
else {
    System.out.println("error");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong binary file. Stockfish binary comes in many different formats and apparently the one that works for my local didn't work on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

`output` stream closes itself. When you run a command, create a new process or this command must block a stream and await an input.

Recommend ProcessBuilder, it is more easily to configure:

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("cmd.exe", "/c", "command")
                    .directory(new File(path))
                    .redirectInput(new File(path, "input.txt"))
                    .redirectOutput(new File(path, "output.txt"))
                    .redirectError(new File(path, "runtime_error.txt"))
                    .start()
                    .waitFor();
```

Comment: Error occurs on the first call to output.flush() which is invoked by the UCIEngine constructor. So I'm not sure how the output stream could be closed if it was just instantiated.

Comment: try a process builder it is more user friendly